Best Approach for Client-Side Encryption with AWS KMS, Separate Keys for Each Column, and Key Rotation
I'm working on implementing client-side encryption in my application, using AWS KMS for key generation. I aim to have a separate key for each column that needs encryption, and the encryption process should be performed on the fly. Additionally, I'm interested in understanding key rotation best practices.
I'm particularly confused about whether to create one key for all columns or a separate key for each column. Obviously, creating one for each looks more secure, if so, how to create keys on the fly(whenever new column added/modified with encrypt:true option). Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
PS: I use typeorm & RDS(postgres)

"creating one for each looks more secure" it might look more secure, but whether it's actually more secure depends on the key policies and how credentials are handled.  I would caution that if the application reads all the columns anyway, it needs access to all the correpsonding keys, and just one key is probably about as secure as many.

If you need to create keys on the fly, the best way to do it would probably be to integrate it into your migration phase, perhaps as a post-migration step that can list keys, list table columns, and then ensure each column has a key and each keys' assigned column is still extant.  I would consider using KMS aliases to specify the keys' assigned instance, schema, table, and column.  You could tag the key, but KMS doesn't support listing keys with tags so that would be a lot of calls to ListResourceTags, whereas you can list aliases in one set of paginated calls.

Keep in mind also that KMS keys aren't super cheap.  At about $1/mo, a few keys costs essentially nothing, but hundreds of keys might quickly cost more than the rest of your infrastructure!

Thanks for the insights! I work with PHI data, so I felt going the extra mile would be better!... But the cost for storing keys is kinda high TBH... My question is - does everyone go with a single key for all columns or unique keys for each column?
